# Convert PDF File to binary encoded string and store into SQL Server without using BULK

Tags: sql, pdf, binary-data, bulk, openrowset

I need to read a PDF file and convert that into Binary string into SQL server but I cannot use BULK operation , I cant not use the below code any alternative to BULK

```
DECLARE @pdf VARBINARY(MAX)

SELECT @pdf = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\j070\Desktop\Test.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;

SELECT @pdf, DATALENGTH(@pdf)
```

Comment: can you check, I don't think the N goes after BULK

Comment: that might or might not but the issue is I do not want to use BULK